# Scraping Ethnicity from Wikipedia

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am interested in scraping ethnicity from wikipedia for celebrities. My idea is, I am having a list of 9 million actors, for which I want to get their ethnicity and study that.

The ethnicity that I am interested in is also pre-defined and I need to search from the same only.

Now, I am assuming that, I have three actors, for example -

```
names = ['Chris Hemsworth', 'Paul Walker', 'Al Pacino']
```

and the ethnicity are -

```
eth = ['American', 'GreaterEuropean', 'British', 'WestEuropean, 'Italian', 'WestEuropean, 'French', 'EastEuropean', 'Jewish', 'Germanic', 'Nordic', 'Asian', 'GreaterEastAsian, 'Japanese', 'GreaterEuropean', 'WestEuropean', 'Hispanic', 'GreaterAfrican, 'Africans', 'Asian', 'EastAsian', 'GreaterAfrican, 'Muslim', 'Asian', 'IndianSubContinent']
```

So, what i am doing is I am searching wikipedia and reading all the page for each name and then looking for the word in ethnicity is it exists.

```
import urllib
link = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"


for name in names:
    search = link+str(name)
    urllib.urlopen(search).read()
```

I am stuck here, I want to create the output dataframe as the following, for example...

```
Names             Ethnicity
Chris Hemsworth   American
Paul Walker       Germanic
Al Pacino         Asian
```

Comment: So how would that work? Wiki of Chris Hemsworth doesn't contain any information about his ethnicity for example

Comment: My thoughts exactly @erocoar. How exactly does searching for the word "Chris Hemsworth" return a value "GreaterEuropean"? Am I missing something about the url en.wikipedia.org/wiki that will somehow translate someone's name into an arbitrary value?

Comment: @erocoar  I am assuming it in the way, if any of the word from eth list is present in the text in wiki page page, then it will take that only to produce resultant df, I can add more words in the eth list such as American for Chris Hemsworth.

Comment: Not trying to be rude here, but have you looked at wikipedia's pages? Where do they contain an ethnicity list for actors??? The closest thing might be the "Born" data?

Comment: @JacobH no,  i have my own list of words which i am looking into the wiki page, please see eth list in my code

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://ethnicelebs.com/) may be the best scrapable listing of actors' ethnicities:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
names = ['Chris Hemsworth', 'Paul Walker', 'Al Pacino']
final_results = {}
for name in names:
  r = requests.get('http://ethnicelebs.com/{}'.format('-'.join(name.lower().split()))).text
  try:
    data = re.findall('(?<=Ethnicity: )[a-zA-Z]+', soup(r, 'lxml').find('strong').text)
    final_results[name] = data[0]
  except:
    final_results[name] = 'Ethicity not found'

table = pd.DataFrame([[a, b] for a, b in final_results.items()], columns = ['Name', 'Ethnicity'])
```

Output:

```
              Name Ethnicity
0        Al Pacino   Italian
1  Chris Hemsworth     Dutch
2      Paul Walker   English
```